# how to make csv file split the lines appropriately?

Tags: excel, csv, head, wc

I have an enormous csv file, about 100 M.   I try to do a `head` on it, and it spits out the entire csv, regardless of the number of lines I ask for.

`head data.csv`
AND
`head -1 data.csv` give the same result, i.e. the entire file.

I notice later that there are no lines in the file at all:

`wc -l data.csv`
`0 data.csv`

I open the csv in excel, and it looks as it should.  And, I save it again as a csv.

How do I get the lines back in my `csv` file?

Comment: Are you sure the csv file is not a single massive-length row? FWIW, if there is no newline at the end of the file, `wc -l` will output 0 even though there is really one line.

Comment: This may be a result of different newline characters being used by `head` and Excel. Have a look at http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/ for details.

Comment: There is no Python problem here

Comment: @lemonhead, that's very likely, and that's what I would guess is the problem.

Comment: @TillHoffmann, that's interesting, but it doesn't seem to offer any suggestions for how to solve this.

Comment: I tried `sed 's/\^M/\'$'\n/g' data.csv > new_data.csv` to convert the `^M` into newline characters.  Everything is still on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the invisible character `^M`:

```
cat -vets data.csv >> new_data.csv
```

Then, this replaces the invisible character, `^M` with the newline character `$\n`:

```
sed -i .copy 's/\^M/\'$'\n/g' new_data.csv
```

then when you `head new_data.csv`, you see that the lines are separated appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this utility function from itertools, since file handle
is iterable.

def head(n, iterable):
    from itertools import islice
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))

# to get first 20 rows
head(20,open('file.csv'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I try this out, like so:  `new_file = head(20, open('file.csv'))`, it completes.  But, I try to slice the `new_file` by doing `new_file[0]`, but it just hangs forever.

Comment: @Hunle. I am not sure why it hangs in you case. I have just tested on csv file, it works fine. Solutions from itertools are reliable ones.  try with open('file.csv') as f:
    head(20, f)

Comment: Thanks, although it still hangs.  I checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289526/the-wc-l-command-shows-zero-lines-on-csv-file?rq=1) out, and I do see the `^M` characters in it.  But, even if I `cat -vets data.csv >> data_copy.csv`, it `data_copy.csv` still has this problem.

Comment: @Hunle do you run head function that I posted from python script? All the function needs is a file handle. if you can with open(you_file) as f: for line in f print(line), you should be able to use head() that I have posted.

Comment: Still hangs.  Because, as @lemonhead and I suspected, it's all on one long row.  So, when I try to read in the file as you say, and print each line, it gets hung up on the first line.

Comment: @Hunle try this: try:
    with open("data.csv") as f:
      for line in f:
          print(line)
except OSError as e:
    print('file openning error: {}'.format(e))

Comment: The `except ` block doesn't seem to catch the error, it just hangs when it tries to print the line, probably because the line is too long to fit in the print queue.  Do you mind including backtics in your comments for ease of readability?  Thanks!!!